# Scheduled Task for the Print Screen Key

Tags: windows, windows-xp, clipboard

Is there any way to setup a scheduled task to "press" the print screen key every 10 minutes? I want to copy the entire screen to the clipboard every 10 minutes. I cannot find much documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a third party software for this. One program I recommend is [SnapShot](http://www.sadmansoftware.com/snapshot/). You can set the interval, image format, destination (clipboard, printer, file).

Comment: It looks like I may have to resort to third party tools. I used a macro recorder and recorded myself pressing the Print screen button. Then I made an executable file from this. I am going to leave the question unanswered for a bit to see if someone else has a solution. Thanks